# How to replace server file in Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm using Electron + Pepper to load an old browser game. The game file is https://example.com/game.swf. It loads from page https://example.com/game.html and I can't access this page. How can I make electron replace game.swf locally so game.html will access local copy of the game? I can't redirect to another URL because of CORS or something else.

I searched every place but didn't found the solution. I tried replacing URL, tried redirecting using intersectFileProtocol and onBeforeRequest but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me:

Create a buffer protocol interception handler, in it check the url and if it points to the file you want to replace then load the file otherwise make an https request to the original site.

```js
const https = require('https');

  mainWindow.webContents.session.protocol.interceptBufferProtocol("https", (req, callback) => {
    if (req.url.indexOf("hi.html") !== -1) {
      callback({
        statusCode: 200,
        data: readFileSync(__dirname + "/local.html"),
        mimeType: "text/html"
      })
    } else {
      https.request(req.method, {
        method: req.method,
        headers: req.headers,
      }, (res) => {
        let data = [];
        res.on('data', chunk => {
          data.push(chunk);
        });
        res.on('end', () => {
          callback({
            statusCode: res.statusCode,
            headers: res.headers,
            data: Buffer.concat(data)
          })
        })
      }).on('error', err => {
        console.log('Error: ', err.message);
      }).end()
    }
  })
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for reply, but when I run this code I get error: certificate has expired

Comment: try using http instead of https: `require('http');`
certificate expires most likely means that the website you are using has an expired SSL certificate, maybe you told your browser to ignore the warning for that specific file